# Is it even possible to keep backslash in PHP string when encoding via JSON?

Tags: php, regex, json, escaping

I have searched through every post about this.

The problem is, in my case a use is occasionaly entering a backslash in its text. I serialize input data and put it as JSON into the database. I do this via PHP (JSON encode and JSON decode).

But everytime someone enters a \ backslash, my json is not valid. I temporary fixed this by replacing backslashes with forward slashes before encoding. Every post I read is about removing the slashes, changing them, but none I can found is about keeping an actual backslash in your text.

How would I realize this? Any help muchly appreciated.

EDIT:
Since I got downvotes like xmass gifts I will put some code here:

page.php, contains my HTML form, this is a ripped version:

```
    <tr><input type="text" value="default" onchange="showValues()" id="name_0" name="name[0]" style="float:left">
    <input type="text" value="" onchange="showValues()" id="weight_0" name="weight[0]" style="float:left">
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <input type="text" value="default" onchange="showValues()" id="name_1" name="name[1]" style="float:left">
    <input type="text" value="" onchange="showValues()" id="weight_1" name="weight[1]" style="float:left">
    </tr>
```

Then, a use can submit the button, which calls exactly this js action:

```
function save(){
 var formData = $jq("#rows :input").serializeArray();
 $jq.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "saveform",
    data: formData,
    }).done(function( result ) {
        $jq("#msg").html(result);
    });
}
```

And than finally, the saveform function:

```
$jsondata = json_encode($postdata) //this is the data passed by ajax request
//and here is an sql query pushing this to the database
```

When the $postdata contains a backslash the json_encode breaks. I get invalid json or something. I do a little processing on the postdata, and also I use htmlentities there to encode html chars from user input (because I have richtext inputs also). Could it be because of the HTML entities?

Comment: Can you show us the code that errors out when you add a backslash?

Comment: If you have a ``\`` in your data and use PHP's JSON encoding function, then it will escape it for you are the JSON will be valid.

Comment: Please paste the code that is used to serialize and deserialize your data, the code that reads it from the input sources and the code that outputs it.

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't serialize to JSON before inserting into a database anyway. It stops you doing useful searches on them. Use well structured tables and columns instead.

Comment: `echo json_encode("foo\bar");` produces `"foo\\bar"`. If you're losing a backslash, then you're doing something to that string such that it's parsed/executed, which removes a layer of escaping.

Comment: Can it be because my \ is the last character? This is my code:

Comment: json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES). The second param is because I thought that might help, which did not. The value I am encoding (on which it is breaking) is an input value submitted by a user. In javascript I serialize all inputs, pass it to php, convert the array to a 2dimensional array and then json_encode it

Comment: I don`t get the downvotes btw, it is just really not working, this is the JSON string in my database, which I try to decode: 
[{"description":"dfh \","name":"asdgsad"}]

Comment: dfh \ is entered by user input. JSON encodes does not double backslash it or something..

Comment: Your question has no code in it. You are taking some input. It might break there. You are turning it into JSON. It might break there. You are inserting it into a database. It might break there. You are pulling it out of the database. etc. etc. We can't tell what the problem is because the question is missing a lot of information, and you haven't shown us any of the debugging you've done in order to track down at which point the data is breaking.

Comment: So, anyone? This is strange behavior right?

Comment: Where are you getting `$postdata` from, and where is the SQL?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're being hit by PHP's [magic quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php), which were removed in PHP 5.4 due to causing bizarre and hard-to-find errors like this.

You have to [disable them](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) in a `php.ini` file like this:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

Comment: I run on php 5.4+...?

Comment: @user2897757 Then I agree with the other comments; we need actual code, what output you get when you run that code, how it's being output where it breaks, etc